# Select clips content

Tags: html, angularjs

I've been stuck with a little issue.

I have a project in angular which has a html select that in Chrome, clips some of the data I'm displaying.

[image]

you can see how the last line is clipped at the end of the list, making it hard to see the last line.

This issue happens only the first time I expand the select, after closing and expanding again the list, the data shows correctly without the clipping.

Somebody has a clue of how to fix this? The html code lookslike this: http://goo.gl/wc7T9j

```
<select data-icon="arrow-d" name="alternates" id="alternates" ng-model="alternate" ng-multiple="false" ng-change="setAlternateLine()" data-ngm-selectmenu="[]" class="ng-pristine ng-valid">
<option style="display:none" value="">select</option>
<option ng-repeat="alternate in tempOutcome.alternates" ng-if="!!alternate" ng-selected="alternate.points == tempOutcome.points" value="{&quot;price&quot;:198,&quot;points&quot;:-2.5}" style="color:black" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    Washington Nationals 
    -2½
    +198
</option>
<option ng-repeat="alternate in tempOutcome.alternates" ng-if="!!alternate" ng-selected="alternate.points == tempOutcome.points" value="{&quot;price&quot;:163,&quot;points&quot;:-2}" style="color:black" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    Washington Nationals 
    -2
    +163
</option>
<option ng-repeat="alternate in tempOutcome.alternates" ng-if="!!alternate" ng-selected="alternate.points == tempOutcome.points" value="{&quot;price&quot;:127,&quot;points&quot;:-1.5}" style="color:green" class="ng-scope ng-binding" selected="selected">
    Washington Nationals 
    -1½
    +127
</option>
<option ng-repeat="alternate in tempOutcome.alternates" ng-if="!!alternate" ng-selected="alternate.points == tempOutcome.points" value="{&quot;price&quot;:-110,&quot;points&quot;:-1}" style="color:black" class="ng-scope ng-binding">
    Washington Nationals 
    -1
    -110
</option>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Include your code, _in the question_.

Comment: best suggestion is don't use a select, it is one element that is very hard to work with cross browser

Comment: Its too big, thats why I added a link to it: http://goo.gl/wc7T9j

Comment: @Tony That is hardly too big.  That aside, it's a requirement here that questions asking for debugging help must include the reproducible code within the question itself.  Not somewhere else, off-site.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus, its already changed.